# Image and backimage issue on HTML

Tags: html

I have a body which has ocean.png fills up the whole screen

```
 body {
 background: url('ocean.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 100%;

  }
```

Then I want to load another image on top of that.

```
<body>
      <img src="image/bubble/bub0.png" name="bubble" width="100" height="100" alt="bub">
```

But the image bub0 instead of have z higher than the body back image, it shows up on the very top section of upper left in white space and the whole ocean background image got shifted downward.   I would like the bub0 image superimpose on ocean baackground image and have higher z order.

Comment: A background-image is always on the bottom as it is a background not an element. Maybe I'm not understanding what you want. Do you have an example page or anything or some screenshots?

Answer (score 3):

You need to give it a `position: fixed;` as well

```
img[name="bubble"] {
    position : fixed;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    z-index  : 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Background-image will be always in the bottom no matter what. z-index is nothing to do with the issue.

Background-size property is not supported by all browsers, so it doesn't stretch to 100% as you expect. The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.

I think the image `ocean.png` is centered and it doesn't really covers the whole page which gives you a feel like the image is lowered and not in the background.